# Как реализовать рандомизацию текста?

Tags: delphi, текст, случайные-числа

Нужно что бы из такого текста:

> Книга стоит [[100|50|10]] [[рублей|руб|р]].

Получилось насколько вариантов:

> Книга стоит 100 рублей.
>
> Книга стоит 100 руб.
>
> Книга стоит 100 р.
>
> Книга стоит 50 рублей.
>
> Книга стоит 50 руб.
>
> Книга стоит 50 р.
>
> Книга стоит 10 рублей.
>
> Книга стоит 10 руб.
>
> Книга стоит 10 р.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var KolRand,NRand,i:Integer;
    RandGr,RandGrDubl,Str,StrDubl:String;
    Work:boolean;
    RandList: TStringList;
begin
RandList:=TStringList.Create;
Work:= True;
Nrand:= 0;

Str:= 'Эта книга, стоит [[300|200|100]] [[рублей|руб|р]].';
StrDubl:= Str;

while Work do begin
if Pos('[[', Str)=0 then Work:= False;

Inc(NRand); //Кол-во циклов

Delete(StrDubl,1,Pos('[[', StrDubl)-1);
RandGr:= Copy(StrDubl,1,Pos(']]', StrDubl)+1);
RandGrDubl:= Copy(RandGr,3,Pos(']]', RandGr)-3); //100|50|10
Memo2.Lines.Add(RandGrDubl);

KolRand:= CntChRepet(RandGrDubl,'|');

  for i:=0 to KolRand do begin //Цикл равен - 3
  //MoneyArray[i]:= Copy(RandGrDubl,1,Pos('|', RandGrDubl)-1);
  RandList.Add(Copy(RandGrDubl,1,Pos('|', RandGrDubl)-1));
  Delete(RandGrDubl,1,Pos('|', RandGrDubl));

  if Pos('|', RandGrDubl)=0 then RandList.Add(RandGrDubl);

  //Memo2.Lines.Add(Str);
  //Memo2.Lines.Add(RandGr);
  //Memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(KolRand));

  Str:= StringReplace(Str,RandGr,RandList[random(KolRand)],[rfreplaceall]);
  Memo2.Lines.Add(Str);
  end;

//Memo2.Lines.Add(MoneyArray[random(2)]);
//MoneyArray[NRand] := RandGr;

Work:= False;
end;
```

Я заранее не знаю, какой будет текст и сколько будет рандомных блоков в тексте, а значит массивов. Поэтому я заменяю рандомный блок на одно его значение, в диапозоне количества этих значений.

Comment: @Factory, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте список списков. TList содержащий TStringList'ы.
По мере прохождения по строке создавайте новый TStringList со значениями подстановок. У TStringList'а есть свойства Delimiter, DelimitedText и StrictDelimiter, используя их можно подставить любые разделители, в частности |.

Подозреваю, что исходная строка может содержать подстановки не только в конце через пробел, но и вперемешку с текстом, поэтому стоит сохранять шаблон строки.

После того как строка пройдена, циклом будет просто сделать рандомные подстановки в результирующую.

Comment: RandList.Delimiter := '|';

RandList.DelimitedText := '300|200|100';

Это немного облегчит, а как же с подстановкой нужной переменной для каждого рандомного блока?

Comment: сохраняйте исходную строку, заменяя подстановки на что-то типа $001 или просто $$$, потом stringreplace'ом поочередно их заполнять. т.е. было

    Книга стоит [[100|50|10]] [[рублей|руб|р]]

стало

    Книга стоит $$$ $$$

зы StrictDelimiter:=true иначе пробелы тоже будут считаться разделителями...

Comment: Тогда мне надо в памяти держать ассоциации всех блоков, а смысл? Не одно и тоже?!

У меня Delphi 2010, он спрашивает что такое StrictDelimiter =)

Comment: можно и сам блок, просто ассоциация натуральная. i-я подстановка соответствует i-му $$$...

Comment: //Заменяем блок на одну из его частей
    Str:= StringReplace(Str,'[['+RandGrDubl+']]',Rand1List[random(NRand1)],[rfreplaceall]);

Comment: Да, примерно так тоже можно. Я просто предлагал сразу получить все подстановки, потом формировать рандомные строки в цикле. У вас получается, что для каждой рандомной строки вы каждый раз изначальную строку разбираете заново.

Answer (score 2):

Извините, но все опять через одно место.

Во-первых, вспоминаем, что в Паскале очень простой способ конкатенации строк - через оператор +. Во-вторых, очень просто завести два массива строк. Один для чисел, второй для сокращений. Затем выбираете два случайных числа от 1 до 3 (включительно), которые будут индексами строчек в этих массивах. Т.е. получается что-то в таком роде (псевдокод):

```
ar     = {"100", "200", "300"};
suffix = {"р.",  "руб.", "рублей."};
x = rnd(3); y = rnd(3);
my_string = "Книга стоит " + ar[x] + suffix[y];
```

Comment: Я заранее не знаю, какой будет текст и сколько будет рандомных блоков в тексте, а значит массивов. Поэтому я заменяю рандомный блок на одно его значение, в диапозоне количества этих значений.

Comment: "Извините, но все опять через одно место."
По этому я здесь =)

Comment: А что тогда мешает вручную создавать эти массивы? Причем то кол-во массивов и то кол-во элементов в них, которое Вам необходимо? Только тут уже тогда, наверное, будут не чистые дин.массивы, а контейнеры вроде TStringList, но кого это волнует?

Comment: var 1List,2List,3List,4List,5List,6List,7List,8List,9List,10List: TStringList;
begin
1List:= TStringList.Create;
2List:= TStringList.Create;
3List:= TStringList.Create;
4List:= TStringList.Create;
5List:= TStringList.Create;
6List:= TStringList.Create;
7List:= TStringList.Create;
8List:= TStringList.Create;
9List:= TStringList.Create;
10List:= TStringList.Create;

while Work do begin
А как подставлять нужную переменную для оработки следующего блока...?
end;

1List.Free;
2List.Free;
3List.Free;
4List.Free;
5List.Free;
6List.Free;
7List.Free;
8List.Free;
9List.Free;
10List.Free;
end;

Comment: http://goo.gl/0XncN

Answer (score 0):

Если текст будет именно такого формата

> Книга стоит [[100|50|10]] [[рублей|руб|р]]

то рекомендую использовать регулярные выражения, например

```
(\d+)[|\]]/g
```

для поиска и "запоминания" найденных цифр из первой части. К сожалению, ничего не знаю про регулярные выражения в дельфи, но в perl-соместимых языках имелось бы 3 переменные (точнее группы совпадений) вида $1, $2, $3 которые бы содержали 100, 50 и 10. Ну а потом уже, рандомно по индексу вытаскивать выражение типа $[rnd]

Comment: К моему сожалению, я тоже не силён в регулярных выражениях.

Answer (score -1):

```
{to Form1}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var T:TTextRandomaze;
begin
    (*   {1|2|{31|32}}  *)
  Memo2.Text:=T.main(Memo1.Text);
  //{1qqqqq  {1|2|{31|32}} яяяяя1}
end;`введите сюда код`
unit Unit_TextRandomaze;

interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,math, Vcl.StdCtrls;
  Type
   Tarr=array of string;
   TTextRandomaze =record
     function Main( input:string ):string;
     function any_Block( input:string ):Tarr;
     function any_Beta( input:string ):string;
     function CountPos(const subtext: string; Text: string): Integer;
   end;

implementation
function TTextRandomaze.Main( input:string ):string;
var   arr:Tarr;
i:integer;
begin

    arr:=any_block(input);

    for I := 0 to length(arr)-1 do
    begin
      if (pos('{',arr[i])<>0) and (pos('}',arr[i])<>0) then
      Result:= Result+ any_Beta(arr[i])
      else
      Result:= Result+arr[i];
    end;

end;

function TTextRandomaze.Any_Beta( input:string ):string;
var i,len:integer;
begin
   //{1 2 3 | {1|2|{31|32}} яяяяя}
    len:= length(input);
    input:=trim(input);
    Delete(input,len,len);
    Delete(input,1,1);

    if (pos('{',input)<>0) and (pos('}',input)<>0) then
    begin
       Result:= Main(input);
       i := countpos('|',Result)+1;
       Result:= Result.Split(['|'])[ math.RandomRange(0,i) ];
    end
    else
    begin
        i := countpos('|',input)+1;
        Result:= input.Split(['|'])[ math.RandomRange(0,i) ];
    end;

end;
function TTextRandomaze.Any_block( input:string ):Tarr;
var i,len,open,close:integer;
 str:string;
begin
    len:=length(input);
    open:=0;
    close:=0;
    for I :=1 to len do
    begin


      if input[i]='{' then
      begin
         if (open=0) and (str<>'') then
         begin
          //найден пустой }...{
          setlength(Result,length(Result)+1);
          Result[length(Result)-1]:= str;
          str:='';
         end;
         inc(open);
      end
      else if input[i]='}' then
      begin
        inc(close);
        if open=close then
        begin
          //найден целый элем {}
          str:=str+ input[i];
          setlength(Result,length(Result)+1);
          Result[length(Result)-1]:= str;
          open:=0;
          close:=0;
          str:='';
          continue;
        end;

      end
      else if i=len then
      begin
       //конец сторки
          str:=str+ input[i];
          setlength(Result,length(Result)+1);
          Result[length(Result)-1]:= str;
          break;
      end;
      str:=str+ input[i];
    end;

end;
function TTextRandomaze.CountPos(const subtext: string; Text: string): Integer;
begin
  if (length(subtext) = 0) or (length(Text) = 0) or (pos(subtext, Text) = 0)
  then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := (length(Text) - length(StringReplace(Text, subtext, '',
      [rfReplaceAll]))) div length(subtext);
end;
end.
```

Доработанный алгоритм 1 рандомизации текста с фигурными и квадратными скобками

```
unit AmTextRandomaze;


interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,math, Vcl.StdCtrls,RegularExpressions,AmList,
  System.Generics.Collections,AmUsertype;
  Type
   Tarr=array of string;

   TTextRandomaze =record
    private
     function Any_serch( input:string ):string;
     function Any_block( input,d_s,d_c:string ):Tarr;
     function Any_Beta( input:string ):string;
     function Any_stirring_Beta( input:string ):string;
     function Any_stirring_Exp( input:string ):string;
     function CountPos(const subtext: string; Text: string): Integer;


     function Emoj_TxtToAlt( input:string ):string;
     function HelpRandomize( input:string ):string;
   public
     ListEmodji:string;
     ListHelpRandomize:string;
     function Main( input:string ; EndYes:boolean=true ):string;
     function HelpRandomize_SerchWord( input:string ):string;

     // показть где ошибка в рандомизации
     function HelpRandomize_Check( input:string;out Msg:string ):Integer;
     function HelpRandomize_CheckUser(Memo:TCustomEdit;Lab:TLabel ; EndYes:boolean=true):string;
   end;

implementation

(*
   Add('〈','〉');
   Add('(',')');
   Add('{','}');
   Add('[',']');
   Add('<','>');
*)
function TTextRandomaze.HelpRandomize_CheckUser(Memo:TCustomEdit;Lab:TLabel ; EndYes:boolean=true):string;
var R:TTextRandomaze;
  Msg:string;
  Input:string;
  P:integer;
begin
    Result:='';
    Input:=Memo.Text;
    P:= R.HelpRandomize_Check(Input,Msg) ;
    if P>0 then
    begin
      Memo.SelStart:= P-1;
      Memo.SelLength:= 2;
      Memo.SetFocus;
      Lab.Caption:=Msg;

    end
    else
    begin
      Lab.Caption:='';
      try
         Result:= Main(Input,EndYes);
      except
       on e:exception do
       Lab.Caption:=e.Message;
      end;
    end;

end;
function TTextRandomaze.HelpRandomize_Check( input:string ;out Msg:string ):Integer;
begin
  if not AmStringHlp.IsMisBrackets(input,['{','['],['}',']'],Msg,Result) then
  Result:= 0;
end;


function TTextRandomaze.Main( input:string; EndYes:boolean=true ):string;
var  count,i:integer;
s:string;
begin
  // showmessage('in'+input);
    if trim(input)='' then exit;


    if EndYes then
    begin
       if pos('*END*',input)<>0 then
       begin
         count:= countpos('*END*',input)+1;
          for I := 0 to count+10 do
          begin

             s:= input.Split(['*END*'])[math.RandomRange(0,count)];

             if s.Replace(' ','').Replace(#10,'').Replace(#13,'')<>'' then
             begin
                break;
             end;
          end;
          input:=s;

       end;
    end;

   input:= input.replace('{{NAME}}','%NAME%');
   input:= input.replace('{{Name}}','%NAME%');
   input:= input.replace('{{name}}','%NAME%');
   Result:=  Any_serch(input);
   Result:=  HelpRandomize(Result);


   Result:=  Emoj_TxtToAlt(Result);
   Result:=  Result.replace('%NAME%','{{NAME}}');
   Result:=  Result.replace(' #13 ',#13#10);
   Result:=  Result.replace('#13 ',#13#10);

   Result:=  trim(Result);

   //showmessage('Result='+Result);
end;

function TTextRandomaze.HelpRandomize_SerchWord( input:string ):string;
var Arr:Tarray<string>;
  I,Max: Integer;
  ser1,ser2:string;
begin
    arr:= ListHelpRandomize.Split(['*END*']);
    Max:= length(arr);
    Result:= '';


    for I := 0 to Max-1 do
    begin

      if (pos('||',arr[i])<>0)then
      begin

          ser1:=arr[i].Split(['||'])[0];
          ser2:=arr[i].Split(['||'])[1];
          ser1:=trim(ser1);
          ser2:=trim(ser2);
          if (ser1<>'') and  (pos(ser1,input)<>0) then
          begin
              if (ser2<>'') and (pos('{',ser2)<>0) and (pos('}',ser2)<>0) then
              begin
                Result:= ser2;
                break;
              end;
          end;

      end;

    end;

end;
function TTextRandomaze.HelpRandomize( input:string ):string;
var Arr:Tarray<string>;
  I,Max: Integer;
  ser1,ser2:string;
begin
    arr:= ListHelpRandomize.Split(['*END*']);
    Max:= length(arr);
    Result:= input;
    if Result='' then exit;

    for I := 0 to Max-1 do
    begin

      if (pos('||',arr[i])<>0)then
      begin

          ser1:=arr[i].Split(['||'])[0];
          ser2:=arr[i].Split(['||'])[1];
          ser1:=trim(ser1);
          ser2:=trim(ser2);
          if (ser1<>'') and  (pos(ser1,Result)<>0) then
          begin
              if (ser2<>'') and (pos('{',ser2)<>0) and (pos('}',ser2)<>0) then
              begin
                // showmessage(ser2);
                  ser2:=  Any_serch(ser2);
                  Result:= Result.Replace(ser1,ser2);
              end;
          end;

      end;

    end;



end;
function TTextRandomaze.Emoj_TxtToAlt( input:string ):string;
var
//RegEx:TRegEx;
MatchCollection:tMatchCollection;
i:integer;
InLines,LinesList,Alt:string;
L:TstringList;
begin

   Result:=  input;
   if trim(input)='' then exit;
  // if trim(ListEmodji)='' then exit;





   MatchCollection:=TregEx.Create('(\d|)&#(\_|)\d+;').Matches(input);
   for I := 0 to MatchCollection.Count-1 do
   begin
     InLines   := MatchCollection.Item[i].Value;
     LinesList := TregEx.Create('\|\|'+InLines+'\|\|.*\|\|').Match(ListEmodji).Value;

     if LinesList<>'' then
     begin
        Alt:=LinesList.Split(['||'])[2];
        input:=input.Replace(InLines,Alt);
     end
     else
     begin
        input:=input.Replace(InLines,'');
       // showmessage('Удален не найденный эмоджи '+InLines);
     end;

   end;

  Result:=  input;

end;












function TTextRandomaze.Any_serch( input:string ):string;
var   arr:Tarr;
i:integer;
begin
{
  if not Check then
  begin
    if (DL_Open='')
    or (DL_Close='')
    or (DL='') then
    raise Exception.Create('Error DL_... is empty. Necessary ');

    Check:=true;
  end;
 }

    if trim(input)='' then exit;
    arr:=any_block(input,'{','}');
    Result:='';
    for I := 0 to length(arr)-1 do
    begin

      if (pos('{',arr[i])<>0) and (pos('}',arr[i])<>0) then
      Result:= Result+ any_Beta(arr[i])





      else
      Result:= Result+arr[i];


    end;
    setlength(arr,0);
    arr:=any_block(Result,'[',']');
    Result:='';
    for I := 0 to length(arr)-1 do
    begin



      if(pos('[',arr[i])<>0) and (pos(']',arr[i])<>0) then
      Result:= Result+ any_stirring_Beta(arr[i])


      else
      Result:= Result+arr[i];
    end;

end;
function TTextRandomaze.Any_Beta(  input:string ):string;
var i,len:integer;
str:string;
begin
   Result:='';
   //{1 2 3 | {1|2|{31|32}} яяяяя}
   if input='' then exit;
    len:= length(input);
    input:=trim(input);
   if input='' then exit;
    Delete(input,len,len);
   if input='' then exit;
    Delete(input,1,1);
   if input='' then exit;


    str:= Any_serch(input);
    if str='' then exit;

    i := countpos('|',str)+1;
    Result:= str.Split(['|'])[ math.RandomRange(0,i) ];


end;
function TTextRandomaze.any_stirring_Beta( input:string ):string;
var len:integer;
begin
   Result:= '';
   //[1 2 3 | [1|2|{31|32}] яяяяя]
   if input='' then exit;
    len:= length(input);
    input:=trim(input);
  if input='' then exit;
    Delete(input,len,len);
  if input='' then exit;
    Delete(input,1,1);
   if input='' then exit;

    if (pos('[',input)<>0) and (pos(']',input)<>0) then
    begin
       Result:= Any_serch(input);
    end

    else
    begin
        Result := input;
    end;

   Result:= any_stirring_Exp(Result);

end;
function TTextRandomaze.any_stirring_Exp( input:string ):string;
var i,len,Lb,Le:integer;
A:Tarr;
str:string;
begin
   Result:= '';
   Result:= input;
   if Result='' then exit;

    // showmessage(Result);
     len := countpos('|',Result);
     for I := 0 to len do
     begin
          setlength(A,length(A)+1);
          A[length(A)-1]:= Result.Split(['|'])[i];
     end;
     len:=length(A);
     for I := 0 to len-1 do
     begin
        Lb:=math.RandomRange(0,len);
        Le:=math.RandomRange(0,len);
        str:= A[Lb];
        A[Lb]:= A[Le];
        A[Le]:=str;
     end;
     Result:='';
     for I := 0 to len-1 do
     begin
       Result:= Result+a[i];
     end;


end;
function TTextRandomaze.Any_block( input,d_s,d_c:string ):Tarr;
var i,len,open,close:integer;
 str:string;
begin
    setlength(Result,0);
    if input='' then exit;
    len:=length(input);
    open:=0;
    close:=0;
    for I :=1 to len do
    begin


      if input[i]=d_s then
      begin
         if (open=0) and (str<>'') then
         begin
          //найден пустой }...{
          setlength(Result,length(Result)+1);
          Result[length(Result)-1]:= str;
          str:='';
         end;
         inc(open);
      end
      else if input[i]=d_c then
      begin
        inc(close);
        if open=close then
        begin
          //найден целый элем {}
          str:=str+ input[i];
          setlength(Result,length(Result)+1);
          Result[length(Result)-1]:= str;
          open:=0;
          close:=0;
          str:='';
          continue;
        end;

      end
      else if i=len then
      begin
       //конец сторки
          str:=str+ input[i];
          setlength(Result,length(Result)+1);
          Result[length(Result)-1]:= str;
          break;
      end;
      str:=str+ input[i];
    end;

    if open<>close then
    begin
    setlength(Result,0);
    raise Exception.Create('Error TextRandomaze пропушена фигурная или квадратная скобка');
    end;


end;

function TTextRandomaze.CountPos(const subtext: string; Text: string): Integer;
begin
  if (length(subtext) = 0) or (length(Text) = 0) or (pos(subtext, Text) = 0)
  then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := (length(Text) - length(StringReplace(Text, subtext, '',
      [rfReplaceAll]))) div length(subtext);
end;
end.
```

2й алгоритм той же рандомизации то со своими правилами

```
unit AmTextRandomization;

interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,math, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Generics.Collections,AmSystemBase,AmList,AmUsertype;

  type
   TAmTextRandExecution = class
      type
       TBase =class;
       TBaseClass =class of TBase;

       TPraviloItem = class
         B,E:Char;
         AClass:TBaseClass;
       end;
       TListPravilo = TList<TPraviloItem>;
       TPravilo = class
        strict private
         FList :TListPravilo;
         function IndexofB(B:Char):integer;
         function IndexofE(E:Char):integer;
         function IndexofClass(AClass:TBaseClass):integer;
        protected
          ItemDefault:TPraviloItem;
          property List: TListPravilo read FList;
        public
          constructor Create;
          destructor Destroy;override;
          procedure Registred(B,E:Char;AClass:TBaseClass);
          procedure UnRegistred(B,E:Char); overload;
          procedure UnRegistred(AClass:TBaseClass);  overload;
       end;


       TListBase = class (TList<TBase>);

       TBase = class
         private
          [weak]FPravilo:TPravilo;
         protected
          TextFull:string;
          ListReady:TListBase;
          procedure Parse();virtual;
          property Pravilo: TPravilo read FPravilo;
         public
          function Get:string;virtual;
          constructor Create(APravilo:TPravilo;ATextFull:string); virtual;
          destructor Destroy;override;
       end;
       TMain = class (TBase)

       end;

       TCircle = class (TBase)
         public
          function Get:string;override;
          constructor Create(APravilo:TPravilo;ATextFull:string);override;
       end;

       TSquare = class (TBase)
         public
          function Get:string;override;
          constructor Create(APravilo:TPravilo;ATextFull:string); override;
       end;

       TValue = class  (TBase)
         protected
          Value:string;
          procedure Parse();override;
         public
          function Get:string;override;
          constructor Create(APravilo:TPravilo;ATextFull:string); override;
       end;

     public
     // class var Pravilo =
      class function Execution(AText:string):string;
   end;

implementation


{ TAmTextRandExecution }

class function TAmTextRandExecution.Execution(AText: string): string;
var P:TPravilo;
    B:TMain;
begin
    P:= TPravilo.Create;
    try
     P.Registred('{','}',TCircle);
     P.Registred('[',']',TSquare);
     B:=TMain.Create(P,AText);
     try
       Result:= B.Get;
     finally
       B.Free;
     end;
    finally
      P.Free;
    end;
end;


{ TAmTextRandExecution.TBase }

constructor TAmTextRandExecution.TBase.Create(APravilo: TPravilo;
  ATextFull: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FPravilo:= APravilo;
  TextFull:=  ATextFull;
  ListReady:=TListBase.Create;
  Parse;
end;

destructor TAmTextRandExecution.TBase.Destroy;
var i:integer;
begin
   for I := ListReady.Count-1 downto 0 do
     ListReady[i].Free;
   ListReady.Clear;
   FreeAndNil(ListReady);
   FPravilo:=nil;
   TextFull:='';
  inherited;
end;

function TAmTextRandExecution.TBase.Get: string;
var i:integer;
begin
   Result:='';
   for I := 0 to ListReady.Count-1 do
   Result:= Result + ListReady[i].Get;
end;

procedure TAmTextRandExecution.TBase.Parse;
var Stack:TStack<TPraviloItem>;

   procedure LocCreateBlock(Item:TPraviloItem;APosBegin,APosEnd:integer);
   begin
       ListReady.Add(Item.AClass.Create(Pravilo,Copy(TextFull,APosBegin,APosEnd-APosBegin)));
   end;

var x:integer;
CurChar:Char;
Item: TPraviloItem;
PosBeginSave,Index:integer;
ASelfClass:TClass;
s:string;
begin
   Stack:=TStack<TPraviloItem>.Create;
   try
      Index:=1;
      ASelfClass:=self.ClassType;
      PosBeginSave:=Index;

      while Index<=length(TextFull) do
      begin
        CurChar:= TextFull[Index];
        for x := 0 to Pravilo.List.Count-1 do
        begin
          Item:= Pravilo.List.List[x];
          if CurChar = Item.B then
          begin
              if (Stack.Count = 0) then
              begin
                 if PosBeginSave < Index then
                 LocCreateBlock(Pravilo.ItemDefault,PosBeginSave,Index);
                 PosBeginSave:= Index + 1;
              end;
              Stack.Push(Item);
              break;
          end
          else if (CurChar = '|')  and (Stack.Count = 0) and (ASelfClass<>TMain) then
          begin
                 LocCreateBlock(Pravilo.ItemDefault,PosBeginSave,Index);
                 PosBeginSave:= Index + 1;
                 break;
          end
          else if CurChar = Item.E then
          begin
             if (Stack.Count = 0) or (CurChar<>Stack.Peek.E) then
             raise Exception.Create('Error TextRandomized');
             Stack.Pop;
             if Stack.Count = 0 then
             begin
                 if PosBeginSave < Index then
                 LocCreateBlock(Item,PosBeginSave,Index);
                 PosBeginSave:= Index + 1;
             end;
             break;
          end;
        end;
        inc(Index);
      end;
      if Stack.Count  = 0  then
      begin
            if PosBeginSave < Index then
           LocCreateBlock(Pravilo.ItemDefault,PosBeginSave,Index);
//           PosBeginSave:= Index + 1;
      end
      else raise Exception.Create('Error TextRandomized 2');
   finally
    Stack.Free;
   end;

end;


{ TAmTextRandExecution.TCircle }

constructor TAmTextRandExecution.TCircle.Create(APravilo:TPravilo;ATextFull: string);
begin
     inherited ;
end;

function TAmTextRandExecution.TCircle.Get: string;
begin
  if ListReady.Count>0 then
    Result:= ListReady.List[math.RandomRange(0,ListReady.Count)].Get
    else Result:='';
end;

{ TAmTextRandExecution.TSquare }

constructor TAmTextRandExecution.TSquare.Create(APravilo:TPravilo;ATextFull: string);
begin
    inherited ;
end;

function TAmTextRandExecution.TSquare.Get: string;
var ArrIndex:TArrInt;
i:integer;
begin
  Result:='';
  if ListReady.Count>0 then
  begin
    AmMath.RandomIndexList(ListReady.Count,@ArrIndex);
    for I := 0 to ListReady.Count-1 do
    Result:= Result +  ListReady.List[ArrIndex.Arr[i]].Get;
  end;
end;

{ TAmTextRandExecution.TValueDefault }

constructor TAmTextRandExecution.TValue.Create(APravilo:TPravilo;ATextFull: string);
begin
     inherited ;
     Value:= ATextFull;
end;

function TAmTextRandExecution.TValue.Get: string;
begin
    Result:= Value;
end;

procedure TAmTextRandExecution.TValue.Parse;
begin
end;


{ TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo }

constructor TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.Create;
begin
    inherited;
    FList :=TListPravilo.Create;
    ItemDefault:= TPraviloItem.Create;
    ItemDefault.B:=#0;
    ItemDefault.E:=#0;
    ItemDefault.AClass:= TValue;
end;

destructor TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.Destroy;
var i:integer;
begin
   for I := FList.Count-1 downto 0 do
     FList[i].Free;
   FList.Clear;
   FreeAndNil(FList);
   FreeAndNil(ItemDefault);
  inherited;
end;

function TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.IndexofB(B: Char): integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to FList.Count-1 do
    if FList.List[Result].B = B then exit;
  Result:=-1;
end;

function TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.IndexofClass(
  AClass: TBaseClass): integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to FList.Count-1 do
    if FList.List[Result].AClass = AClass then exit;
  Result:=-1;
end;

function TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.IndexofE(E: Char): integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to FList.Count-1 do
    if FList.List[Result].E = E then exit;
  Result:=-1;
end;

procedure TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.Registred(B, E: Char;
  AClass: TBaseClass);
var Item:TPraviloItem;
begin
   if (IndexofB(B)>=0) or (IndexofE(E)>=0) or (IndexofClass(AClass)>=0) then
   raise Exception.Create('Error TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.Registred дубликат символа или класса');
   Item:=TPraviloItem.Create;
   Item.B:=      B;
   Item.E:=      E;
   Item.AClass:= AClass;
   FList.Add(Item);
end;

procedure TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.UnRegistred(B, E: Char);
var i1,i2:integer;
begin
    i1:= IndexofB(B);
    i2:= IndexofB(E);
    if (i1>=0) and (i1 = i2) then
    begin
      FList[i1].Free;
      FList.Delete(i1);
    end;

end;

procedure TAmTextRandExecution.TPravilo.UnRegistred(AClass: TBaseClass);
var i:integer;
begin
    i:=IndexofClass(AClass);
    if (i>=0) then
    begin
      FList[i].Free;
      FList.Delete(i);
    end;
end;










end.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]